# Access file in external hard drive using python on mac

Tags: python, macos, io

I have a Python file in `/Users/homedir/...` and I want it to access a `csv` file on an external hard drive.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I only need reading permission.

Answer (score 8):

External drives can be found under **/Volumes** on macOS. If you provide the full path and have read access you should be able to read in your csv.

Answer (score 6):

I have USB connected WD 4 TB hard drive that appears as "My Passport for Mac" in finder. I have created a folder called model on this drive and stored a file called model.json

Here is code to read the file.

```
import os
import sys
 # load json and create model

json_file = open('/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/model/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
```

My Mac Mini has 121 GB SSD which I find limiting when I work with huge data for ML exercises. I used to keep getting messages such as "low volume. clean up your disk " often and then I had to clean the files. To work around I bough 4 TB external HD from WD and attached it to MAC mini via USD. I put all my data files and models onto this drive now and it works fine.